# creating a path in wpf programatically

Tags: wpf, canvas, drawing

I have a canvas with a bunch of textblocks spread over.
Each Texbllock has differnt text in it.
I need to wrap these textblocks with different shapes such as circle around one and ellipse around another and a decorative path around another etc.
I am thinking of using a path in wpf to achieve this.
If there is a way to attach a screenshot here it would be easy to look and understand what i am saying but i do not know if it is possible.
I am wondering if anyone could give me some direction how to accomplish this.
Thanks
N

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) reference to shapes and paths drawing in WPF.

Comment: Wow. You added the tag 'telematics' to all GPS tags. Taxinomist badge gaming? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25154/tag-telematics-is-a-new-tag-but-is-currently-synonymous-with-gps

Comment: Yup...went on a tagging spree... However, I didn't do it with the intent of inducing erroneous tagging, as ideed, gps technology is a subset of telematics. Telematics, or telemetry, is a technology that allows remote measurement and reporting of information, thus including a wider variety of fields than just gps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telemetry. I stand by my action, as further questions targeting the integrated use of telecommunications and informatics may very well choose the tag as a valid one.